# Should I build more circular train networks?

Tags: mini-metro

On my Scenic playthroughs, I discovered that ring networks may balance the load from each station from the network. However, it also decreases the efficiency when multiple Locomotives (instead of Carriages) are placed. Since Carriages are rare, when should I build more circular train networks?

Here's that Scenic playthrough. Note that the light blue lane has one locomotive, but it holds up relatively fine; The dark blue lane has three locomotives and it doesn't spread the load well. The yellow lane has a locomotive with a carriage and it works pretty well even when the passengers drop off to reach the Hospital (plus symbol).

[image]

Comment: Even though I don't play this game, I would suggest circular networks because they allow linking multiple stations of the same type in row together without having your locomotive pass them and pick the passengers up when going in the other direction (look at the yellow line with 4 circles in a row). It just logically makes more sense. Also this allows for setups with a special type of station (plus, diamond etc.) without having to worry about the position in the line it self (either on the end or right in the middle). But that's just my opinion.

Comment: You should have connected dark blue to the triangle yellow is connected to, that would make the way shorter for triangles on dark blue.

Comment: One other difficulty I see with your layout is that the corners are often sharp.  In some cases this cannot be avoided, but otherwise the corners should be smoothed out so trains are not forced to stop if there isn't someone to pick up.

Answer (score 11):

Loops in Mini Metro are definitely beneficial.

1. trains can go in either direction
2. you can can control how many are going in each direction
3. it tends to reduce hot spots
4. with a single locomotive doing a loop should decrease the time between visits to the same station.

The negatives are that it might:

1. make you use bridges that you could use elsewhere
2. in *extreme* mode loops prevent you from extending that line again. It is probably best to avoid loops in extreme mode.
3. take up extra passes through a station that would prevent a new line coming to that station after

I find that loops are so good in Mini Metro that I applaud real life systems that have evolved to include them (Chicago, NYC and Paris) and scoff at cities that haven't gotten there (LA, DC, BART in the Bay Area).  It seems obvious from riding BART for a couple of years that a loop would improve reliability and reduce hot spots.